# "The table shows the gender of the listeners who called in to participate in a quiz by a radio station."

Tags: probability

In the image included below, there's a table showing the gender of 15 callers for a radio quiz. 6 are male, 9 are female.

Part a) asks for the experimental probability (as a percentage) that a caller is male (answer: 40%)

Part b) asks for the experimental probability (as a percentage) that a caller is female (answer: 60%)

Part c) asks for the probability that the 16th caller is male. (book says 43.75%)

Part d) asks for the probability that the 100th caller is female. (book says 50%)

How did they get parts c) and d)? This is for a 12-year-old's math class.

[image]

I think this is from the Singapore Mathematics standards series - look at the cover image for grade 3A here:

https://www.singaporemath.com/Primary_Mathematics_Series_s/15.htm
[image: Textbook Cover]

[image: Teacher's Guide]

Comment: Wow, is this for real? Parts c and d seem to require sampling distributions, which I can't believe they'd expect a 12-year old to know. I must be not understanding the problem.

Comment: Judging by the answer to part (c), the book seems to be saying that the probability that the $16$th caller is male is equal to the probability that $7$ of the first $16$ callers are male.

Comment: Maybe they expect that all new callers will be 50-50 male/female, and that the observed bias is just noise that should not be extrapolated. It would explain the answer to (d), but not to (c)...

Comment: @N.F.Taussig I think you've guessed what the problem poser intended. I wonder what model they had in mind to support that reasoning ...

Comment: Please [eidt] the question to tell us the author (and title and publisher) of this book. They may need to be asked to make a correction.

Comment: @DonThousand Yes, I was thinking binomial. Based on the sample, p = .4 and q = .6, making all 4 questions extremely simple, which seems strange.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig Yes, I was thinking of that, and tried binompdf(16,.4,7) in a TI-84, but that would account for any arrangement of these 7 males. Also, it came out to 0.19.

Comment: @EthanBolker How do I edit the question? I'm looking for an edit button but can't see one anywhere. This is my first time ever posting a question here. Send help : )

Comment: Does anyone know how I can add another image to this question? Or even edit it at all?

Comment: Never mind, I finally saw an edit button. I don't think it was there before...

Comment: @Jared I think this is from  Singapore math (see my edit). I have written them to find out how to register my confusion (perhaps politely point out a possible error). I wish I had access to the text. If you want to follow up on this with me you can find my email in my stackexchange profile.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With just the information provided I think you would naturally assume either

- that the call in audience is large and $40\%$ male and all are equally likely to call in. That would make the answers to c) and d) $40\%$ and $60\%$. Then the book is just plain wrong.

or

- that the audience is large and half male half female, which would explain the answer to d) but not to c).

Perhaps there is context with more about the audience or some strange definition of "experimental probability" that leads to the book's answers.

**Edit:** I contacted the publisher. That is in fact an error, known since 2016. The correct answers are $40\%$ and $60\%$.

See the list of errata here:

http://singaporemathematics.com/errata/pdf/6B_std_tg.pdf

Comment: Brilliant. Thank you!

Comment: You're welcome. I don't like to leave that kind of public error dangling. If you accept my answer (the check mark) then this question won't remain on the unanswered queue.

Comment: Found it! ✔️ Thank you